# Dreamweaver regular expression to search and replace

Tags: regex, dreamweaver

I need to search and replace on file this:

```
<?php echo lang_xxxx; ?>
```

To this:

```
<?php echo $lang['lang_xxxx']; ?>
```

How to do this? The lang_xxxx is not unique, can exists anothers like lang_yyyy, lang_zzzz, etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the following expression:

[**Live Example**](https://regex101.com/r/aN7lR4/1)

```
(lang_[^;]*?);
```

and replace it with:

```
$lang['$1'];
```

or:

```
$lang['\1'];
```

---

Results:

> Input: `<?php echo lang_xxxx; ?>`
>
> Output: `<?php echo $lang['lang_xxxx']; ?>`

> Input: `<?php echo lang_es; ?>`
>
> Output: `<?php echo $lang['lang_es']; ?>`